# maths nested superscripts and subscripts displayed incorrectly inline

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, inline

I am having a strange bug when using nested superscripts and subscripts in inline math (displaystyle works fine). This behaviour is the same independently of the font used or the compiler (orginally with `luaLaTeX` with `unicode-math` but also occurs with plain `pdfLaTeX`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

Some text is \(\omega_{m_{ij}}^r\) and \(\omega_{m_{ij}}^{r_{ij+1}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: compare with the output with `\everymath{\displaystyle}`

[image]

Comment: Your image looks OK to me, what do you want it to look like?

Comment: on the second one the subscripts and superscripts are shifted upward

Comment: I guess that is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: You have to think in terms of Boxes here, Latex arranges them always in a way so they don't overlap. Since you add an subscript index to your superscript `r`, its box grows and Tex has to push it upward to avoid intersection with the box of the `m`. If you were to add a superscript to `m` you will notice that this will also push the upper box further up. This is entirely correct though.

Comment: Yes inline math always uses a more cramped style to try to ensure that it fits in the paragraph without disturbing the line spacing. For the same reason inline sum limits are in subscript position rather than below the summation symbol.

Comment: The fact that the `\displaystyle`d output is different, is because in this case Tex doesn't care about the lineheight anymore and thus pushes the `m_{ij}` further down. This means the `r_{ij+1}` can come down to a height closer to where it would put it anyway because now there is enough room. This is normally not the case, because Tex will try to stick to the normal lineheight as much as possible, which leads to the behaviour before the edit.

Comment: since the positioning of the *scripts is exactly as defined in texbook appendix g, i think the title should say "inconsistently" rather than "incorrectly".

Comment: @barbara beeton: Well, I'd say that the positioning is indeed by design, but that the design is somewhat "incorrect", even if this is a kind of abuse of the word "incorrect".

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- well, as knuth's bug collector, i'm just trying to avoid bug reports that wouldn't even get to him, because they'd be rejected in the prescreening by the person designated by dek to do the filtering.  there's already a community wiki question in this forum on the topic: [What would you like to change about TeX/LaTeX/XeTeX/etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/).  you might consider adding a link to *this* question from there.

Comment: @barbara beeton: Ah, now I see. I meant it indeed in the way that this is something I'd like to change about TeX -- thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Max: What you're writing in your second comment is not correct: in `\displaystyle`, TeX pushes the _superscript_ further _up_ because it doesn't care about the lineheight anymore. The effect is that the "minimum distance rule" doesn't take effect yet, and so the subscript stays where it should be.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you can justly regard this strange behaviour as kind of a bug in TeX's sub- and superscript positioning algorithm; it doesn't make sense that *both* the sub- and the superscript are raised. See below for some suggestions on how to fix the problem. At the end I offer a new positioning algorithm, and I compare it with the old algorithm. (Sorry for the length of this answer!)

### What's happening?

The positioning algorithm is laid down in Rule 18 of Appendix G in the TeXbook. Here's what's happening: first, tentative positions of the sub- and superscripts are defined (Rules 18c and 18d). The problem arises in Rule 18e: *only* if the sub- and superscript are too close together (less than four times the default rule thickness, according to the tentative positions), TeX makes sure that the bottom of the superscript is at least as high above the baseline as 80% of the x-height. In this case, the superscript may be raised more than necessary for achieving the minimum distance of four times the default rule thickness, and then the subscript will be raised, too!

To illustrate the problem, I use an `m` as a subscript, and a rule with height 0 and different depths as superscripts:

[image: comparison]

In the first case, the depth is `0.34ex`, in the second case it's `0.35ex`: an imperceptible difference leading to rather different outputs. I don't think that this behaviour is desirable. Note that this only happens due to the `m` having a small height, not for letters like `f` with ascenders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\test[1]{\omega_m^{\rule[-#1ex]{1pt}{#1ex}}}
\begin{document}
$\test{0.34}$ versus $\test{0.35}$
\end{document}
```

Let me point out that the same effect can occur in `\displaystyle`: then superscripts are set a bit higher by default so that the effect appears at a depth of `0.46ex` versus `0.47ex`. So it is a case of good luck that `\displaystyle` helps in your case (as observed in David's answer). Let me point out that in "cramped" style (as used under `\overline` and `\sqrt`) the effect can be quite drastic: `$\overline{a_n^ia_n^j}$` gives

[image: output of \overline]

### Possible ways to fix the problem

I see at least three completely different ways out of the problem; I'm not sure which one to prefer. The **first** idea (see David's second comment to this answer) is to add a strut to the subscript to give it so much height that TeX won't raise it. The following code defines a `\scriptstrut` that is *just* large enough; however, I think that the output is still not optimal: the second superscript is raised too much.

[image: output: superscript raised too much]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts               % initialize math fonts
  \dimen@=\fontdimen5\textfont2  % x-height
  \multiply\dimen@ by 4
  \divide  \dimen@ by 5          % 80% of the x-height
  \advance \dimen@ by \fontdimen17\textfont2
  \@tempdima=\fontdimen8\textfont3
  \multiply\@tempdima by 4       % 4x the default rule thickness
  \advance \dimen@ by -\@tempdima
  \edef\scriptstrut{\noexpand\rule{0pt}{\the\dimen@}}%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\omega_{m_{ij}}^r$ versus $\omega_{m_{ij}\scriptstrut}^{r_{ij+1}}$
\end{document}
```

Now you'd have to add a `\scriptstrut` to all the subscripts that are raised too high. One *could* try to automatize this by making the underscore `_` active (see also mafp's second comment), but it's not easy to do this in a safe way: note that, e.g., `$a_\frac12$` is valid (albeit not recommendable) TeX code.

Here's my **second** idea: by default, TeX places subscripts lower if a superscript is present. You can prevent this by adding

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts %initialize math fonts
  \fontdimen17\textfont2=\fontdimen16\textfont2
  }
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. This doesn't completely suppress the problem, but it makes it a lot less visible. However, there could be other side effects.

### The new positioning algorithm

Probably the **best** way is to use another algorithm altogether for the vertical positioning of a sub-/superscript combination. I offer such a new algorithm in the code below, where I define an `\nss` command (like "natural sub- and superscripts") that takes three arguments, the 2nd being the sub- and the 3rd being the superscript of the 1st.

[image: output]

The rules I use are as follows, keeping as close to the original algorithm as possible: Use the tentative default positions as the TeX engine would do it. To achieve that the sub- and superscript are at least four times the default rule thickness apart, raise the superscript, but only as long as its bottom is at most 80% of the x-height above the baseline. If the distance between sub- and superscript is still too small, lower the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\nss[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox0\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\cramped{#2}$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle#3$}%
  \dimen@=\fontdimen8\textfont3
  \multiply\dimen@ by 4             % 4x the default rule thickness
  \advance \dimen@ by \ht0
  \advance \dimen@ by -\fontdimen17\textfont2
  \@tempdima=\fontdimen5\textfont2  % x-height
  \multiply\@tempdima by 4
  \divide  \@tempdima by 5          % 80% of the x-height
  % Modifications are only necessary if the top of the subscript is not that high:
  \ifdim\dimen@<\@tempdima
    \ht0=0pt                        % don't let the subscript interfere
    \@tempdima=\fontdimen5\textfont2
    \divide\@tempdima by 4          % 25% of the x-height
    \advance \dimen@ by -\@tempdima % if >0, add to depth of superscript!
    \ifdim\dimen@>0pt
      \@tempdima=\dp2
      \advance\@tempdima by \dimen@
      \dp2=\@tempdima
    \fi
  \fi
  #1_{\box0}^{\box2}%
  \endgroup
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
   Original: $\omega_{m_{ij}}^{r_{ij+1}}$,\,
\= improved: $\nss{\omega}{m_{ij}}{r_{ij+1}}$. \\
   Original: $\overline{a_n^i a_n^j}\,$,
\> improved: $\overline{\nss{a}{n}{i} \nss{a}{n}{j}}\,$.
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Finally, a somewhat more extensive comparison between the original and the improved algorithm. I use a box of width `2pt` as a subscript and a box of width `1pt` as a superscript. The subscript has varying heights (but *depth* `0pt`), the superscript has varying depths (but *height* `0pt`). You see a lot of wobbling with the original algorithm!

[image: original versus improved]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\nss[3]{...} % insert code from above!!!
\makeatother
\newcommand\oss[3]{#1_{#2}^{#3}}
\newcommand\test[3]{#1{\omega}{\rule{2pt}{#3pt}}{\rule[-#2pt]{1pt}{#2pt}}}
\newcommand\compare[2]{\test#1{#2}{1}\test#1{#2}{2}\test#1{#2}{3}\test#1{#2}{4}}
\newcommand\oneline[1]{\compare\oss{#1}\qquad\compare\nss{#1}}
\newcommand\threelines[1]{%
  \leavevmode\rlap{Original:}\hphantom{$\compare\oss1$}\qquad Improved: \par
  $#1{\oneline2}$ \par
  $#1{\oneline3}$ \par
  $#1{\oneline4}$ \par}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Cramped style} \par
\threelines\cramped    \medskip
\textbf{Text style}    \par
\threelines\textstyle  \medskip
\textbf{Display style} \par
\threelines\displaystyle
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for tracking down exactly which rule it is, was too tired last night to track through ap G:-)

Comment: While this is a neat explanation, the question of the OP was how to fix that. Any idea?

Comment: @mafp well as it's a documented feature of the tex engine it will not change for any system called TeX, but as Hendrick notes subscripts with more height work more consistently so you could use `_{\strut m}` for example to so that all the subscripts had the same (invisible) height. (By the way the OP ought to accept this answer rather than mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, we can not patch TeX, but it seems one might whip up a workaround for this problem, with an active underscore, some `\mathstrut`, some box measuring... *That* would be a real answer to this question. I would add a bounty for that, but I can't grant one (either because the question is too new, or because it has an accepted answer?). And yes, Hendrik's answer is better than yours, *so far*.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the thumbs up `:-)` Note that a `\strut` has the disadvantage of an additional depth that might be undesirable. But I don't know myself yet how a better algorithm would look like.

Comment: @mafp: Your right, I failed to actually answer the OP's question. I'll think a bit more about it.

Comment: Thanks @Hendrik. Well identifying where the problem comes from is close enough. I have tried both potential solutions and for me only the second one has any effect, but only when using pdflatex, lualatex gives no changes in behaviour. what I see with the second solution is that the subscript is higher and stays there whereas the superscript moves up in my second case.

Comment: @ArTourter: Sorry, I forgot to answer your comment. To be honest, I have no idea why `lualatex` behaves differently with my 2nd suggestion. But for me, the `\scriptstrut` from the 1st suggestion works both with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`. I can post an example.

Comment: @ArTourter: I improved my last suggestion.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Thanks for still looking into this. That indeed look very promising. I'll test it out in my code and will report back.

Answer (score 14):

The default positions of sub and superscripts are closer to the baseline in textstyle as TeX tries to maximise the chance that the expression does not disturb the paragraph line spacing.

Your first example is the standard setting for inline math, however with the larger scripts caused by the subscripting, TeX has to move them further apart.

This is standard layout, however you can use `\displaystyle` to force the less cramped setting even in inline math if line spacing is not a concern.

Comment: Thanks David, I would have understood the behaviour if it just raised the subscript, increasing the space between the 2 but here is raises both by pretty much the same amount. This means that it brings the subscript block higher than it would be in `displaystyle`. I will indeed use `\displaystyle` in the second example as this looks the most consistent with the rest.

Comment: yes the exact rules take up most of appendix G and they do what they do:-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subdepth` package; i wrote a discussion of the issue in a [faq answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-subheight)

Comment: thanks for the comment, however in the example I have, `subdepth` doesn't have much effect. when compiling using `pdfLaTeX` only the subscript of the first one gets raised but the superscripts are still not aligned. And when compiled with `LuaLaTeX`, it has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: The `subdepth` package has a completely different purpose: it takes care that the vertical position of subscripts is the same if there's a superscript or not.